# Genymotion can't connect to network

Tags: android, networking, connection, wifi, genymotion

[image: wifi connect failure]

when I turn on the `wifi` controller of android emulator in `Genymotion`, it can't connect to the network but always show `Obtaining IP address` ,and after a while, it shows `IP` Configuration Failure.
Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: They are android 5.0  and 6.0 emulator.

Comment: It's been resolved.It's been resolved.    Simply choose the Host-only Adapter for Adapter 1 and NAT for Adapter 2. Make sure the cable-connected is selected(ticked). Host-only can be used to create a network containing the host and a set of virtual machines, without the need for the host's physical network interface. Instead, a virtual network interface (similar to a loopback interface) is created on the host, providing connectivity among virtual machines and the host.
This works for me. Hope it helps.

Comment: it's the default set by genymotion. some will still face the problem without change anything